# Compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{( e^{2i\pi x}-1)^2}{|x|^{3/2}}dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Can someone tell me if it's possible to compute the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{( e^{2i\pi x}-1)^2}{|x|^{3/2}}dx.$$
I was trying to separate as 
$$\int_{-\infty }^\infty \frac{e^{4i\pi x}-1}{|x|^{3/2}}dx-2\int_{-\infty }^\infty \frac{e^{2i\pi x}-1}{|x|^{3/2}}dx.$$
Then 
$$\int_{-\infty }^\infty \frac{e^{4i\pi x}-1}{|x|^{3/2}}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{4i\pi x}-1}{x^{3/2}}dx+\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-4i\pi x}-1}{x^{3/2}}dx=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(4\pi x)-1}{x^{3/2}}dx$$
$$=-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(4\pi x)^2}{x^{3/2}}$$
but is there an easy way to compute the previous integral ? I was thinking about residue theorem, but how can I use it here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you managed to get the last integral, then we can proceed as follows: for $0 < s < 2$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(\alpha x)}{x^{1+s}}
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+s)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} (1-\cos(\alpha x)) t^s e^{-tx} \, dt dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+s)} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^s \cdot \frac{\alpha^2}{t(t^2+\alpha^2)} \, dt \\
&= \frac{\alpha^{s}}{\Gamma(1+s)} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan^{s-1}\theta \, d\theta \qquad (t = \alpha \tan\theta) \\
&= \frac{\alpha^{s}}{\Gamma(1+s)} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{s}{2},1-\frac{s}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{\alpha^{s}}{\Gamma(1+s)} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2\sin(\pi s/2)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: that looks awesome ! Just, how do you get the second equality ?

Comment: It follows from Fubini's theorem combined with the following computations: $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} \, dx = \frac{1}{x}, \qquad \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(\alpha x)e^{-tx} \, dx = \frac{t}{t^2+\alpha^2}. $$

Comment: I guess that for the second integral I must use residue theorem, no ? By the way, is dx, not dt ?

Comment: I guess you can try a more straightforward way: $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(\alpha x) e^{-tx}\,dx = \operatorname{Re}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(t+i\alpha)x} \, dx $$ and you can use the first integral to compute this!

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = \sqrt{x} \implies du = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$

$$\begin{align}2\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\cos(4\pi x ) - 1}{x^{3/2}}\, dx =& -4\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin^2(2\pi x)}{x^{3/2}}\, dx&\\=&-8\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin^2(2\pi u^2)}{u^2}\, du \end{align}$$

By integration by parts and $t = 2\sqrt{\pi}u \implies dt = 2\sqrt{\pi} du$

$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin^2(2\pi u^2)}{u^2}\, du = \left[\dfrac{-1}{u}\sin^2(2\pi u^2)\right]_0^\infty +\int_0^\infty 8\pi\sin(2\pi u^2)\cos(2\pi u^2)\, du \\=4\pi\int_0^\infty \sin((2\sqrt{\pi}u)^2)\ du = 2\sqrt{\pi}\int_0^\infty \sin t^2 dt = \dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} $$

So the answer is $-4 \sqrt{2}\pi$.